# Get date value from date picker

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to MVC and I am trying to get the date the user selects from the date picker and display another set of dates based on a user input. The date picker works fine however I am not sure how to get the value of the date and pass it to the calculation. I have created a textbox to get the number of days the user wants displayed and the button to initiate the calculation, however the way I created the button also created another text box.

Here is the view code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <h2>Enter The Number Of Days To Display</h2>
        Date: <input type="text" id="date" name="date"value ="Enter a number"/>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DaysToBeViewed)
       <input type="submit" value="Display Days" />
```

Comment: what plugin you're using for datepicker?

Comment: Are you talking about running the calculation client-side (via JavaScript, in which case, this has nothing to do with MVC) or server-side?

Comment: I want to run the calculation client-side in JavaScript but the balance of the program is written in MVC which is why I stated that. I have edited to reflect the JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with [getDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate)?

```
var currentDate = $( "input#date" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
```

this returns the current date for the datepicker or null if no date has been selected.

You can check the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to see other alternatives (for example onSelect)

regards,
André

Answer (score 2):

1. You can partially post the date value to the controller method. Like this:

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
       {

   ### Enter The Number Of Days To Display

   Date: 
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DaysToBeViewed)
          // change the type to button
          
   }

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submitDate").on("click", function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../MyController/Calculate?date=" + $("input#date").val(),
                                                           // syntax was wrong here
           success: function (result) {
              $("#DaysToBeViewed").val(result);
           },
           error: function () {
             alert("Error in calculation method");
           }
        });
       });
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
public string Calculate(string date) 
{
    // do your calculation here
    return date;
}
```

1. If you want to post your data then you need to change your BeginForm somthing like this:

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Calculate", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, 
                                      new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <h2>Enter The Number Of Days To Display</h2>
        Date: <input type="text" id="date" name="date" value ="Enter a number"/>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DaysToBeViewed)
       <input type="submit" value="Display Days" />
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class MyData
{
    public string DaysToBeViewed {get; set;}
    public string date {get; set;}
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Calculate(MyData myData) 
{
    // do your calculation here
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Adding that javascript code to the view, breaks the jquery datepicker?

Comment: The value of the input can be gotten with simple jQuery's .val() function.